# Prove that $\alpha(r+s+1,r)=\alpha(r+s+1,s)$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am reading [a paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X76900352)

I am having difficulty understanding this part, which is why I posted it on this forum to discuss with you

Let me recall some definitions:

1. Let $\pi = \left(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n\right)$ and $\rho=\left(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n\right)$ be two permutations of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. We call a
   pair of consecutive elements $a_i, a_{i+1}$ in a permutation a rise if $a_i <a_{i+1}$ and a fall if $a_i > a_{i+1}$. There will be $4$ possibilities denoted by RR, FF, RF, and FR if we consider whether each pair $a_i, a_{i+1}: b_{i}, b_{i+1}$ forms a rise or a fall.
2. $\alpha(n, k)$ as the count of pairs of permutations of length $n$ with exactly $k$ occurrences of either RF or FR

On page 229, they wrote that

> To get a more symmetrical version of (3.8) we define
> (3.11) $\quad \alpha^*(r, s)=\alpha(r+s+1, r)=\alpha(r+s+1, s)=a^*(s, r)$,

But I don't understand why $\alpha(r+s+1,r)=\alpha(r+s+1,s)$.

I tried in the following ways:

For a permutation of length $r+s+1$, we can select $r$ pairs out of $r+s+1$ pairs to be RF or FR. Therefore, $\alpha(r+s+1, r) = \binom{r+s+1}{r}$.

Similarly, $\alpha(r+s+1, s)$ is the count of pairs of permutations of length $r+s+1$ with exactly $s$ occurrences of either RF or FR. Therefore, $\alpha(r+s+1, s) = \binom{r+s+1}{s}$.

But I think it is not true. Could you please help me with this problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_{r,s}$ be the set of pairs of permutations of length $r+s+1$ with exactly $r$ instances of RF or FR. This means $|A_{r,s}|=\alpha(r+s+1,r)$, and it means $|A_{s,r}|=\alpha(r+s+1,s)$. To prove that $\alpha(r+s+1,r)=\alpha(r+s+1,s)$, it suffices to find a bijection between $A_{r,s}$ and $A_{s,r}$.

Here is the bijection. Given a pair of permutations $(\pi, \rho)\in A_{r,s}$, then the corresponding pair of permutations is
$$
(\pi^\text{rev},\rho)\in A_{s,r}
$$
Here, $\pi^\text{rev}$ is the reverse of $\pi$. If $\pi=(\pi_1,\pi_2,\dots,\pi_{r+s+1})$ in one-line notation, then $\pi^\text{rev}=(\pi_{r+s+1},\pi_{r+s},\dots,\pi_1)$.

This works because reversing $\pi$ converts all RF and FR pairs into RR and FF pairs, and also converts all RR and FF pairs into RF and FR pairs.

Comment: thank you very much